# Selenium - How to get following sibling?

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, automation

So I want to target a textbox that appears in a list that comes after the label "First Name" and send a first name to the box, but can't seem to be able to target the textBox...

What I've tried:

```
        WebElement firstNameLocTry = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[text()='First Name']/following-sibling::div"));
        firstNameLocTry.sendKeys(firstName);
```

What the li look like:

```
<li class="WPTO WKVO" role="presentation" data-automation-id="formLabelRequired">

<div class="WBUO WETO WDUO">
<label id="56$551056--uid24-formLabel" data-automation-id="formLabel" for="56$551056--uid24-input">First Name</label>
<div class="WEUO wd-c8594868-6b31-4526-9dda-7d146648964b" aria-hidden="true">First Name</div>
</div>

<div data-automation-id="decorationWrapper" id="56$551056" class="WFUO">
<div class="WICJ">
<div class="WMP2 textInput WLP2 WJ5" data-automation-id="textInput" id="56$551056--uid24" data-metadata-id="56$551056" style="visibility: visible;">
<input type="text" class="gwt-TextBox WEQ2" data-automation-id="textInputBox" tabindex="0" role="textbox" id="56$551056--uid24-input" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true">
</div>
</div>
</div>

</li>
```

Any reason my sendKeys just leads to Element not interactable?

Comment: Well you're trying to `sendKeys` to the `<div class="WEUO wd-c8594868-6b31-4526-9dda-7d146648964b" aria-hidden="true">First Name</div>` which is not interact-able

Answer (score 1):

The attached HTML code Produce below out put

[image]

With the given XPath points to the second "First Name" Div [below pic], when you perform *sendKeys*, it is obvious that the error "*Element not interactable*" will be thrown.

[image]

Try with below two Xpaths,

```
1. //label[text()='First Name']//parent::div/following-sibling::div
2. //label[text()='First Name']//parent::div/following-sibling::div//input
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use following xpath:

```
//div[text()='First Name']
```

or try:

```
//*[contains(text(),'First Name')]
```

Comment: This actually ends up throwing me a brand new error: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[text()='First Name']/following-sibling::div"}    Am I missing something here?

Comment: can you share url link i can double check in page and let you know ?